# Array Dinamico Multidimencional con JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, array

Buenas Noches querida comunidad, en esta Oportunidad vengo por aca solicitando nuevamente su preciada ayuda y es que estoy trabajando en un modulo de un proyecto el cual requiere de Array Dinamico Multidimencional y lo estoy Trabajando con JQuery, ahora Bien lo primero que deben saber es que tengo 2 div's;

== Datos de Interes ==

-> El Primero (1ero) => Contiene Varios Input's de tipo Radio, las cuales son los Controles.
-> El Segundo (2do) => Contiene tambien Varios Input's de Tipo Checkbox, las cuales son las Posiciones de los controles.

== Problema ==

Ahora Bien, necesito obtener en un Array cuyos indices sean los values de los controles, el arreglo de las posiciones y que cada indice(control) se le agreguen o se le resten las posiciones, sin que me afecte el proximo indice agregar en el Array, es decir, cada indice en el array debe agregar sus posiciones sin afectarme el indice nuevo.

== Lo Esperado ==

```
Array [
  control1:[pos1,pos2,pos3...],
  control2:[pos2,pos4,pos5...]
]
```

donde control1 o control2 son los indices, por tanto seria el Par

```
Clave:Valor[],
Clave:Valor[]
```

== Lo Probado Hasta Ahora ==

= Codigo HTML =

```
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="con">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Control</legend>
                                <input type="radio" value="control1" />
                                <input type="radio" value="control2" />
                                <input type="radio" value="control3" />
                                <input type="radio" value="control4" />
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>                        
                        <div id="pos">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Posición</legend>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="posicion" value="pos1" />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="posicion" value="pos2" />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="posicion" value="pos3" />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="posicion" value="pos10" />
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

= Codigo JQuery =

```
                    caja = new Array();

                    var ctrl = $.map($("input:radio:checked"),function(val){
                        return val.value;
                    });
                    var posi = $.map($("input:checkbox:checked"),function(val){
                        return val.value;
                    });

                    for(var i in ctrl){
                        caja.push({ctrl:ctrl[i],posic:posi});
                    }
                    console.log("CAJA: %o",caja);
```

= Resultado =

```
  CAJA: 
  (2) [{…}, {…}]
  0:
  ctrl: "control1"
  posic: (2) ["pos1", "pos2"]
  __proto__: Object
  1:
  ctrl: "control2"
  posic: (2) ["pos1", "pos2"]
  __proto__: Object
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

== NOTA ==

Cabe Resaltar que Estoy mostrando los datos en un Objeto porque no he podido hacerlo totalmente como arreglos es por eso que estoy por aca solicitando la ayuda de todos ustedes colegas :-)

Bueno Espero me Logren Ayudar estare esperando una excelente respuesta de ustedes y que me puedar dar una mano con este problema.

== POSDATA ==

Si de dato extra les Sirve: la Relacion entre control-posicion debe ser de 1 a muchos, es decir, 1 control puede o debe tener muchas posiciones.

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que planteas, das muchas explicaciones pero no es muy claro. Para hacerlo simple: ¿cómo de deben llenar los arrays? ¿qué debe ocurrir cuando se chequea o se deschequea un radio o un checkbox? ¿por qué no usas un solo elemento (radio o checkbox poniendo más información en ellos, haciendo uso por ejemplo de los atributos `data-*`? Agradecería que dediques un primer párrafo de tu pregunta a describir el problema y el contexto de una manera simple. Luego puedes dar todas las explicaciones que quieras. Quisiste ser claro pero no se llega a comprender la lógica que sigues.

Comment: Buenos Dias Cedano, Amigo lo que necesito es crear un Array que se muestre asi como lo indico en (== Lo Esperado ==),
Esto para generar un Array dinamico, es decir, que se guarde tanto el control con sus posiciones....

Comment: Creo que es bueno saber cómo funciona tu código y cuál es el contexto para poder darte una buena alternativa de solución. Leyendo la pregunta no logra entender aspectos básicos del mismo. Surgen muchas preguntas, como las que te hice en el anterior comentario, de las cuales no me dices absolutamente nada. A veces no hay que centrarse en lo que quieres y tratar de obtenerlo a toda costa, porque hay alternativas mejores o maneras más óptimas de construir la lógica de un programa.

Comment: Bueno Fijate, para responderte sobre lo del contexto, estoy haciendo un modulo de OdontoDiagrama, esto es sobre (Odontologia) lo cual es usado para que el dentista identifique los trabajos realizados en los dientes y los que se van a realizar, Ahora bien, se necesita obtener esa Data, por lo cual se tienen 2 div's, uno para el Control = (caries,reparacion,exodoncia...) y el otro div es para las posiciones de los dientes, lo que necesito que cada control este casado con sus posiciones de forma independiente, tal cual como lo estoy mostrando en la seccion (== Lo Esperado ==).

Comment: Bueno ahora vemos un poco más de luz en el asunto. Y yo me pregunto, ¿por qué no manejar un objeto que represente el estado de una dentadura? Yo no sé mucho de odontología, pero imagino que una dentadura es **un objeto definible**, que cada diente tiene un nombre y una posición. Por cada paciente tú muestras ese objeto y marcas lo que tienes que marcar. No sé si me explico. Eso se puede hacer perfectamente con un solo elemento y los atributos data. ¿Te imaginas algo como que por cada paciente te muestre un dibujo de la dentadura y allí seleccionas: *este diente, este tratamiento*?  ...

Comment: ... Eso es perfectamente realizable con los atributos data. Yo lo haría así, en vez de complicarme la vida con una lógica que como quiera es muy deficiente y poco práctica. En lenguaje llano: construir un elemento completo que represente una dentadura y seleccionar en él o que haya que seleccionar.

Comment: ok y me podrias dar una ayuda con eso mostrandome un ejemplo sencillo y funcional ??

Comment: Revisa el código de la respuesta. No sé si es exactamente lo que necesitas, pero si observas se aplica una lógica muy simple basada únicamente en el `id` de cada checkbox. Si necesitas algo más complejo se puede también hacer echando mano de atributos `data-` o de una lógica más refinada todavía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una lógica sencilla que hace uso del `id` de cada checkbox para saber qué elemento fue marcado. En esta convención por ejemplo, `ci` sería el colmillo izquierdo,  `cd` el colmillo derecho...

El código Javascript determina con `querySelectorAll` todos los elementos que fueron marcados y los guarda en un array, y hace lo mismo con los elementos que no fueron marcados.

Viendo cada valor en el array sabrás qué dientes fueron marcados como enfermos y cuáles no.

Esto es como dije una lógica sencilla. Se pueden hacer cosas más avanzadas, como relacionar cada diente con un tipo de tratamiento, etc. Si necesitas algo así, explicando bien lo que necesitas se pueden extender el alcance del código, aplicando siempre la lógica que sea más práctica.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var btnEnviar=document.getElementById("btnEnviar");
  btnEnviar.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      var allChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
      var allNotChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)')
      var dientesBien = [];
      var dientesMal = [];

      allNotChecked.forEach(function(elem) {
        dientesBien.push(elem.id);
      });

      allChecked.forEach(function(elem) {
        dientesMal.push(elem.id);
      });

      console.log(`Dientes bien: ${dientesBien}`);
      console.log(`Dientes mal: ${dientesMal}`);
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-2pUeJf+y0ltRPSbKOeJh09ipQFYxUdct5nTY6GAXswA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<h2 class="subtitle">Marque los dientes que están mal</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div id="izquierda">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Izquierda</legend>
      <label>Colmillo</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ci" /><br />
      <label>Molar 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="m1i" /><br />
      <label>Molar 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="m2i" />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div id="cols">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Derecha</legend>
      <label>Colmillo</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cd" /><br />
      <label>Molar 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="m1d" /><br />
      <label>Molar 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="m2d" />
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<a id="btnEnviar" class="button is-primary is-outlined">Ver Estado Dentadura</a>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @A. Cedano, tu respuesta me es de utilidad, estaré realizando pruebas con ello...lo único es que al OdontoDiagrama que tengo debo también lleva los controles que serian en este caso lo que el dentista va hacerle al diente Ejemplo: Exodoncia, Caries, Reparación, entre otras. Lo cual debo casar con las posiciones de los dientes bien sean Izquierdos o Derechos como me lo muestras en tu Ejemplo...
de igual manera como te dije, estaré realizando pruebas con tu ejemplo aplicandolo en mi Modulo.
Agradecido por tu Respuesta Amigo, Cualquier inquietud te la haré saber...

Comment: @oarodriguez como te dije, la lógica se puede extender y mejorar. Yo haría lo siguiente: pondría (fijo o por programación, eso habría que verlo)  un atributo `data-*` a cada elemento diente y en ese atributo el tipo de tratamiento que lleva. En el mismo recorrido que se hace sobre `allChecked` puedes modificar los elementos  o puedes por ejemplo construir una especie de interfaz de asignación de tratamientos, donde pones cada diente marcado y varios checkbox con el tratamiento, o puedes poner una sola interfaz donde hagas todo de una vez. Eso depende de qué requerimientos tengas.

Comment: ... yo pensándolo bien optaría por lo último: una interfaz de asignación donde pongo todos los dientes y cuando marque alguno muestro al lado un contenedor (usando el evento onclick) para seleccionar el o los tratamientos que necesita ese diente y eso irlo escribiendo en un atributo  `data-*` de cada diente. Al final tendrás grabado en cada diente su estado y el tratamiento que necesita y podrás mostrarlo como se hace al recorrer `allChecked`